# jquery append a clickable function

Tags: jquery, append, toggle, parent-child

I am trying to append some text that when clicked, hides the element it is appended to, but remains viewable, and then when it is clicked again, makes the element re-appear:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('<span class="click-me">Click Here For Filter Options</span>').insertBefore('.searchandfilter');

    $( ".click-me" ).click(function() {
        $( ".searchandfilter" ).css( "height", "0px" );
    });
 }
 });
```

I know I should be using the toggle function but I am a bit lost as to how to implement it as I can't even get the element to hide on click.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If an element is hidden, all children will be hidden.

Comment: what if I use .insertBefore() ? or possibly use position absolute on the child and simply reduce the height of the parent to 0?

Comment: if the element exists outside of the element that is hidden, sure.  but so long as it is a child of an element that is display: none, regardless of what you do, it will be hidden.

Comment: so would insertBefore() achieve this? Or can you provide the code that would help me achieve this?

Comment: insertBefore adds the element outside of the target, so yes it would display regardless of the target.

Comment: I've adjusted my code to:           jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('<span class="click-me">Click Here For Filter Options</span>').insertBefore('.searchandfilter');

$( ".click-me" ).click(function() {
  $( ".searchandfilter" ).css( "height", "0px" );
});

}
});    however, the span does not show?

Comment: Can you add that to your question?  you can use Ctrl+M to bring up the onsite editor to create a working example of the issue.

Comment: edited, thanks for your assistance on this

Comment: edited it for formatting.  it looks like you have an extraneous `}` at the end. Can you please use Ctrl+M to make a working example of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra `}` was cause of breaking code and using `toggle()` made show and hide working.

Here is the fixed version of your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('<span class="click-me">Click Here For Filter Options</span>').insertBefore('.searchandfilter');

    $( ".click-me" ).click(function() {
        // Use toggle instead
        //$( ".searchandfilter" ).css( "height", "0px" );
        $( ".searchandfilter" ).toggle();
    });
 //} /* extra, cause of breaking */
 });
```

This is another way :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var $clickMe = $('<span/>',{
        class:'click-me',
        text:'Click Here For Filter Options'
    });

    $clickMe.insertBefore('.searchandfilter');

    $( ".click-me" ).click(function() {
        $( ".searchandfilter" ).toggle();
    });

 });
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3usgqt7n/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `}` in your example, which is probably why it's not working.

Here's a working example, which I have tidied up a bit.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/gRNQqo)

jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) works nicely here.

```js
$(function() {
    $('<span>Show/Hide Filter Options</span>')
        .insertBefore('.searchandfilter')
        .click(function() {
            $(".searchandfilter").toggle();
        });
});
```

```html
<div class="searchandfilter">Some content</div>
```